NextJS - In production build Page with Mui <Container> throw error 500
I'm using MUI all over my page, one of my pages however seems to not working properly. On dev mode  (next dev) things works fine, with production build (next build + next start) first request on URL throws error 500. With same error as below. Funny is that page actually work right after just initial request is 500, but page get rendered as normally and end user will not spot any issue at all. However for bots this is critical error.
Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at t (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at F (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
    at $ (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:90488)
    at rC (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:33840)
    at n$ (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59861)
    at nj (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64628)
    at nO (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64035)
    at n$ (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:62224)
    at nj (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64628)
    at nP (C:\Develop\carcheck-frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:56390)

I believe it is somehow related to MUI + server rendering. But I'm not sure how exactly.
If I change component template to this things works:
<main>
<h1 style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }}>{t('vehicleHistoryReport')}</h1>
 <Grid container spacing={0} style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
  <FAQ lng={lng} />
 </Grid>
</main>

If I change it to:
   import {Container}} from '@mui/material'
   <main>
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
    <h1 style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }}>{t('vehicleHistoryReport')}</h1>
     <Grid container spacing={0} style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
      <FAQ lng={lng} />
     </Grid>
     </Container>
    </main>

It will throw an error.
Above is obviously minimal example, production page error can be also find in: https://rb.gy/o6rjhu
Network tab from browser:

My versions:

next - 14.0.4
@mui/material - ^5.15.4
@mui/material-nextjs - ^5.15.3

Did someone else had similar issues? Or can someone to point me to the right direction how can I debug this more?

For some reason yarn upgrade fixed my issue, not sure what exactly was a problem but it is working now.
